# how to get value with PostBack and stop jumping page

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, data-binding

Here I'm tried with

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       If(IsPostBack==null)
    }
```

above control. I want to stop jumping page at every time 
and bing values from database.

Comment: It looks like you want to avoid post back - learn about ASP.NET Ajax. Bing it or Google it.

Comment: not getting proper link to solve some where some one suggest me to use MVC but am new for mvc my data command is week in mvc please recommended me.

Comment: As @YK1 suggested you should try ASP.NET AJAX. You don't need to switch to MVC for that. If you don't want to refresh the full page but only part of it (single DIV tag for example), then AJAX is your answer. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"` on the `aspx` page.